What is the significance of the wild animals in Isaiah 43:20?
Specifically, are the תַּנִּ֖ים, sometimes translated "jackals", sometimes "dragons", and sometimes simply "wild animals" to be understood as symbolic of evil, like the serpent of Eden?
And why do they appear often in scripture paired with לִבְנ֥וֹת "owls" or "daughters(!)"? (e.g. Isa 34:13; Job 30:29; Mic 1:8)

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

The significance is the comparison of God's people to the wild animals of the wasted lands.  Isaiah is remonstrating with Israel for not knowing what was good for them, whereas the wild beasts of the field knew to follow the waters God provided for them in the desert lands.
The word "tannah" in Isa. 43:20 is Strong's Heb 8577 properly defined as dragon, sea monster, or serpent Biblehub).  At Mal 1:3 it is Strong's H8568 of the same derivative "tan" and means a female dragon - jackal (Biblehub).  The translators chose to use "jackal" in place of dragon because of the dry, waterless desert wilderness of the scripture.  Isa 43:20 was describing beasts of the wasted wilderness, and not oceans.
Symbolically, dragons were used as a metaphor for evil and wicked people such as Pharoah in Ezek. 29:3.  God compared the sins of Israel to the poison of dragons in Deu. 32:33. God compared Nebuchadnezzar to a dragon in Jer. 51:34.
Habitations of dragons were wasted lands, and the meaning in those verses related to lands inhabited only by the wild beasts and animals that could thrive in desert or waterless lands.  Therefor, some of the translations chose the word "jackal" or sometimes "hyenna" that people recognized for wild desert animals.
The translation depends upon the context.

The exact meaning of the Hebrew word תַּנִּין (tanniyn) is not certain and is variously translated as the OP has documented.

In Gen 1:21, Job 7:12 it appears to be "sea monsters"
In Ex 7:9, 10, 12, Deut 32:33 it appears to be "serpent"
I Job 30:29, Ps 44:19, it appears to be dragons, eg, the crocodile??

In Isa 27:1 and 51:9 (according the BDB) this creature appears to be a "mythological personification of chaos".
In Ps 74:13 & Eze 29:3 it appears to be a symbol of Pharoah and thus, perhaps the crocodile.
In all its other places, it appears to be literal.  Specifically, Isa 43:20 simply uses the word to name one of several wild animals for which God provides food and water.

תַּנִּים != * תַּנִּין*, the OP asked about תַּנִּים from Isa 43:20, which is a different word from the crocodile/serpent/sea monster you're referencing

@AviAvraham - I think that is the difference between singular and plural.

err no, תַּנִּים is the plural of תַּנָּה. They may be related but not in a singular/plural way
